# Understanding the units of the equations

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, unit-of-measure

I am reading a paper and there are some equations whose units I do not understand and hope some one can help. The paper is this for the reference (all the equations are in page 2):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym9m026r9eyg4ug/aj-86-6-AJ0860061006.pdf?dl=0

**Equation 1:**

[image]

DP = in meter; BD =  Mg per meter cube

**Question 1:** How does DP has units in meters?

**Equation 2**

[image]

SW = mm
BD = Mg per meter cube
Zm = meters

**Question 2:** What will be the units of the wiggly symbol? In the paper, they say it is dimensionless and hence I suspect it has no units

**Equation 3**

[image]

DD = meters; DP = meters; wiggly symbol = not sure what will be the units based on question 2;

**Question 3:**: Why is the unit of DD in meters

Comment: The pdf you've linked to requires the users to pay in order to view it . Please provide some other way to view it as i think the answer is there in the paper.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @TheIntegrator thank you. I have provided the link to the paper where you can read it. Regards

Comment: this does not seem to be correct. you cant use a variable with unit as an argument of transcendental function.

Comment: I am not really from a maths background so I could not understand your comment here. Apologies. I am trying to write a code to implement these equations but need to know what are the units of these equations for my sake.

Comment: what i think @physshyp said is that if you have a variable within some [transcendental function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function) then it has to be unit less. 

    Also if you're  coding , you need not include the units in the algorithm, you just just do the calculations and print the unit along with the output.  BTW : the wiggly symbol is the "section sign" (§)  use alt+21

Comment: Thank you. In the paper they said § is a scaling parameters which I suspect is dimensionless. What I meant with code is that, I just need to understand the units of each of these equations since my original data has a different units and I need to convert them before I can use them in this equation.

Comment: See [this](http://web.mit.edu/2.25/www/pdf/DA_unified.pdf) pdf page 20 , maybe that helps you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @physshyp noted,
we can't use a variable with unit 
as an argument of transcendental function - 
in this case $\exp$ and $\log$,
the argument must be dimensionless.

But such expressions,
which make an impression that
the argument has some unit,
are not seldom, (especially in engineering)
and they works.

They works, because
in fact these arguments are dimensionless,
but it is not stated clearly.

We need to assume 
that there is also a scaling factor,
which eliminates all units and makes 
the argument properly dimensionless.

Sometimes there are already constants which
clearly must have units,
for example, in this one

\begin{align}
\operatorname{DP}
&=
1.0+\frac{2.5\operatorname{BD}}{\operatorname{BD}+\exp(6.53-5.63\operatorname{BD})}
,\quad \operatorname{DP}(\mathrm{m})
,\quad \operatorname{BD}(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3})
\end{align}

the constant $1.0$ clearly must mean $1.0$m,
the constant 6.53 must be dimensionless,
and the constant 5.63 must have units, 
that are reciprocal to units of $\operatorname{BD}$,
that is, it must be $5.63\,\tfrac{\mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{mg}}$.

Ok, we now have fixed the argument of $\exp$. But what
a mess we have with $\operatorname{BD}+\exp(\dots)$:

\begin{align}
\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3} 
\quad + \quad
\text{just some plain number?} 
\end{align}

what it even mean, you might ask?

In order to make some sense, 
we just need to assume
that there is unspoken scaling constant 
$1$ with the same units as $\operatorname{BD}$,
as a factor of the $\exp$:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{DP}(\mathrm{m})
&=
1.0(\mathrm{m})
+\frac{2.5(\mathrm{m})\cdot\operatorname{BD(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3})}}
{\operatorname{BD}(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3})
+1(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3})
\cdot
\exp(6.53-5.63(\tfrac{\mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{mg}})
\cdot
\operatorname{BD}(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3}))}
.
\end{align}

And the last constant used, 
$2.5$ must be in meters in order to have 
a unit-balanced expression.

Unfortunately, in practice all this 
lengthy description is often omitted.

We can follow the same pattern 
to easily
"fix" the other formulas.

\begin{align}
\S&=
\frac{\operatorname{SW}}{(0.356-0.144\operatorname{BD})\operatorname{Z_{M}}}
,\\
\quad&\operatorname{SW}(\mathrm{mm})
,\quad
\operatorname{BD}(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3})
,\quad
\operatorname{Z_{M}}(\mathrm{m})
.
\end{align}

Since the authors state that $\S$
is just a scaling factor,
the aforementioned expression 
must be considered as

\begin{align}
\S&=
\frac{\operatorname{SW}(\mathrm{mm})}
{(0.356-0.144(\tfrac{\mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{mg}})
\cdot
\operatorname{BD}(\tfrac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{m}^3})
)\operatorname{Z_{M}}(\mathrm{m})}
,
\end{align}

And the third case

\begin{align}
\operatorname{DD}&=
\operatorname{DP}
\exp\left[
\ln
\left(
\frac{0.5}{\operatorname{DP}}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\frac{1-\S}{1+\S}
\right)^2
\right]
\end{align}

can be "fixed" as just

\begin{align}
\operatorname{DD}(\mathrm{m})&=
\operatorname{DP}(\mathrm{m})
\cdot
\exp\left[
\ln
\left(
\frac{0.5(\mathrm{m})}{\operatorname{DP}(\mathrm{m})}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\frac{1-\S}{1+\S}
\right)^2
\right]
.
\end{align}

Comment: This answer makes me fall in love with maths. Very nicely and well explained. Kudos to you!

Comment: @Crop89: Nice to hear that, thanks!